# Asp.net core uploading file and storing file url to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the code working in a new seperate test project how ever it will not work with my excisting work project. I am trying to upload a file as part of a form, store it in a folder in wwwroot and store the url in a database. I have posted the code below.The program compiles and runs but does not store anything when create button is pressed. any help would be greatly appreciated.

//Model

```
namespace PostProjectEvaluations.Web.Models
{
public partial class Projects
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Manager { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

}
public class ProjectsVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

//Controller

```
namespace PostProjectEvaluations.Web.Controllers
{
    public class projectsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IApplicationRepository ApplicationRepository;
        private readonly PostProjectEvaluationsContext _context;
        private IHostingEnvironment mxHostingEnvironment { get; set; }
        private object objproject;

        public projectsController(IApplicationRepository applicationRepository,
            IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, PostProjectEvaluationsContext context)
        {
            mxHostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            ApplicationRepository = applicationRepository;
            _context = context;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.dataSource = ApplicationRepository.GetAllProjects().ToList();
            var projects = ApplicationRepository.GetAllProjects();
            return View(projects);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ProjectsVM projectsVM)
        {
            if (projectsVM.File != null)
            {
                //upload files to wwwroot
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(projectsVM.File.FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(mxHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads", fileName);


                using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await projectsVM.File.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
                }
                //your logic to save filePath to database, for example

                Projects projects = new Projects();
                projects.Name = projectsVM.Name;
                projects.FilePath = filePath;

                _context.Projects.Add(projects);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return View("Index");
        }
  public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var project = ApplicationRepository.GetProjects(id);
            return View(project);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {

            var project = new Projects();
            return View(project);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Projects projects)
        {
            ApplicationRepository.Create(projects);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }



        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var project = ApplicationRepository.GetProjects(id);
            ApplicationRepository.Delete(project);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var project = ApplicationRepository.GetProjects(id);
            //mxApplicationRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View(project);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Projects projects)
        {
            ApplicationRepository.Edit(projects);
            //mxApplicationRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }

}
```

//View

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Projects" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-body">
            <h3 class="form-section">Project Info</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Project Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Project Manager</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input asp-for="Manager" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
            </div>

            <!--/span-->
        </div>
        <h3 class="form-section">Project Files</h3>
        <!--/row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
                        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn blue-assembly" name="submitButton" value="Save" />
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn default" onclick="cancelClick()">Cancel</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you check if `projectsVM` has a value? i don't think that the model binder is able to bind your input field to this variable because the name on the input field is "files". You could try something like `List<IFormFile> files` as your parameter in the save function

Comment: Double check that your file is not null, and I think you'll have to replace `WebRootPath` with `ContentRootPath`. also check your Debug folder from where your application is ran maybe it's saving the file there.

Comment: In debug output i get this error, Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FilePath', table 'PostProjectEvaluations.dbo.Projects'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1):

Include your model in view as in the first line

```
@ProjectsVM
```

You have to give the same name as a model 
Try this:

```
   <input type="file" id= name="File" multiple />
```